# How to launcn a vm on ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services

With Azure, when we connect to a cloud machine, we can install Hyper-V on top of it and can load multiple vms inside the VM again.

But similar option is not found in the aws ec2 instance.

Any suggestion on how to enable it if any such option.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Just launch a number of small VMs directly in AWS. The T series are low to moderate resource, low cost instances.

Comment: Because I have a preconfigured virtualbox VM. And rebuilding that is not feasible at present

Answer (score 1):

In Azure, its sounds like you use Nested Virtualization.

Instead you can try on **AWS EC2 bare metal**
[Hyper-V on EC2 Bare metal](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-hyper-v-on-amazon-ec2-bare-metal-instances/)